# AngularJS Directive not executing

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an Angular Directive that looks like this:

```
angular.module("Module").directive("ValidateGreaterThan", ["angular-underscore", function (_) {
    "use strict";

    console.log("directive works");
    return {
        require: "ngModel",
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            console.log("directive works");
        }
    }
}]);
```

The markup:

```
      <input placeholder="eg. 10" type="number" name="minutes" 
          required 
          validate-greater-than="0"
          data-ng-model="settingsController.model" />
```

Unfortunately, neither of my console logs are showing up. Any idea why? The file is showing up in devtools, so it's loading properly, and the `angular.module("Module")._invokeQueue` correctly shows the directive listed.

Comment: Drop the first char of the directive name to lowercase: `.directive("validateGreaterThan"`

Comment: @JAAulde, ack that's embarrassing. I'm getting a different error now, but it looks to be unrelated. Do you want to post your comment as an answer? I'm happy to accept it.

Comment: I appreciate it, but it's just a simple typo. I'm all for leaving it in the comments and closing it out. :)